# reformat DateTime Array

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have generated an Array of dates with the following code using jodatime

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime] 
=Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))

val from = new DateTime(2000, 06, 30,0,0,0,0)
val to = new DateTime(2001, 06, 30,0,0,0,0)
val by = new Period(0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0)

val range = { dateRange(from ,to, by)}

val dateRaw = (range).toArray
```

How can I pass `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMdd")` to each value in order to get an Array of integers of format yyyyMMdd

Array[Int] = Array(20000630,20000830,20001030...

Comment: Just curious, why integers? wouldn't it make more sense to do String?

Comment: because then I can use it as a value in Spark SQL an do sort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMdd")
dateRaw.map(d => f.print(d).toInt)
```